# How to disable crsf protection in @WebFluxTest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

Why am I receiving a `403 FORBIDDEN` for the following test?

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public Mono<String> accept(Authentication authentication) {}
}


@WebFluxTest(MyServlet.class)
@WithMockUser
public class MyServletTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        webClient.post().url("/")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<403 FORBIDDEN>

> POST /
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Content-Type: [application/json]

No content

< 403 FORBIDDEN Forbidden
< Content-Type: [text/plain]
< Cache-Control: [no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate]
< Pragma: [no-cache]
< Expires: [0]
< X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
< X-Frame-Options: [DENY]
< X-XSS-Protection: [1 ; mode=block]
< Referrer-Policy: [no-referrer]

CSRF Token has been associated to this client
```

As far as I know, `@WebFluxTest` disables csrf. So why is it complaining?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
webClient.mutateWith(SecurityMockServerConfigurers.csrf()).post()...;
```

Comment: SecurityMockServerConfigurers.csrf()

Answer (score 11):

This is happening because you probably have `spring-boot-starter-security` in your classpath. You need to create a config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebFluxSecurityConfig {
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.csrf().disable().build();
  }
}
```

and import it into your test with

```
@Import(WebFluxSecurityConfig.class)
```

Apparently the SecurityConfig is not loaded by default in `@WebFluxTest`.

I found the solution here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16088

Comment: ah thank-you, it wasn't imported the config when i had the @Profile({"local", "test" ... })

Answer (score 0):

You can load the default configuration using `@SpringBootTest` together with `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` to have the test client configured and injected. Put both annotations on your test class.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this is because you have got spring-security dependency in your classpath.

In my case, it was Spring Reactive application, and the Security Configs is applied by creating a bean and annotate it with **@EnableWebFluxSecurity**

```
  @Configuration
   @EnableWebFluxSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig {
   
@Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.oauth2Client();
    return http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll().and().build();
  }
}
```

So, by default the nature of SpringSecurity config, CSRF will be enabled.
Now we have to decide the solution based on the question **"Do you need CSRF enabled for your application?"**
If the answer is yes then your test should also use csrf which can be done by `webClient.mutateWith(csrf()).post()`
If csrf is not required to be enabled, then disable it by `http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll().and().csrf().disable().build();`

That should help you with the issue.